# Track download / upload transfers (size)

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Service (C#) that has about 10 methods 5 for getting data (.NET Dataset) and 5 for updating data (.Net Dataset).

Example of methods:

```
// getting data from Method    
public DataSet GetEmployeeContractInfo(Guid uid)
            {

                DataSet ds = null;
                Database db = InfoTacto.Framework.WebServices.Common.GetDatabase();

                using (DbCommand cmd1 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sp_employee_contractinfo_get"))
                {

                    db.AddInParameter(cmd1, "employeeuid", DbType.Guid, uid);
                    ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd1);
                }

                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "contract_info";
                }
                return ds;

            }

/// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ds"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool UpdateEmployeeContractInfo(DataSet ds)
        {
            bool returnVal = true;

            Database db = Common.GetDatabase();
            DbConnection conn = db.CreateConnection();
            conn.Open();
            DbTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

            try
            {
                if (ds != null && (
                    (ds.Tables.Contains("contract_info") && ds.Tables["contract_info"].Rows.Count > 0)
                    )
                    )
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["contract_info"].Rows)
                    {
                        if (dr.RowState == DataRowState.Modified || dr.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
                        {
                            using (DbCommand cmd1 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sp_employee_contractinfo_change"))
                            {

                                db.AddInParameter(cmd1, "employeeuid", DbType.Guid, dr["employeeuid"]);

//... all other parameters

                                db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd1,trans);
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
                trans.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                trans.Rollback();
                returnVal = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Cleanup
                conn.Close();
            }


            return returnVal;
        }
```

20 of my users will be using **WIFI** via **celular** modem because they are in a place that traditional WIFI is not accessible, so I need to track how much bandwidth is comusing my WCF Service for getting data and for uploading data by method, that way if I have that information I can really know if they consume more bandwidth that the one tracked by the `WCF Service` then they are looking at videos, etc. and human resources can take actions.

Any clue? I was thinking on checking the size of each `dataset` object before sending the `dataset` to the client and then store that value into a database table and also doing the same when receiving a dataset from the client.

Comment: `DataSet`?  Have you ever seen what a `DataSet` looks like when it's serialized?  Creating your own objects and serializing them as `DataContract` will reduce the bandwidth footprint, quite possibly significantly.

Comment: The hole application is huge and would be terrible to convert all WCF services from dataset to custom objects

Comment: I agree with Tim. It is strongly discouraged to return `DataSet` objects from your service. See what Scott Hanselman has to say: [Returning DataSets from WebServices is the Spawn of Satan and Represents All That Is Truly Evil in the World](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx).